# Is it possible to concatenate variables on fly and make string subsitution on the result?

Tags: bash, string-concatenation, substitution

String substitution with single variable:

```
FOO=fooo
echo ${FOO%o}
```

The output for this is: `foo`.

How to do this with concatenation? Something like this:

```
FOO=fooo
echo ${FOO$FOO%o}
```

The output for this is (my wish): `fooofoo`.

*If this is possible at all.*

---

In other words, I would like to concatenate several strings (using variables) and then apply string substitution to entire string (concatenation of all variables), not just single variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you show the expected outputs?

Comment: @ShawnChin, I am looking a way to apply substitution to concatenation, you showed the code for concatenation of substituted string. The order of executing functions makes the difference.

Comment: OK. now I get you. AFAIK there isn't a way to do that as a single bash operation. You'll need to perform the concatenation into a variable first follow by the required parameter substitition

Comment: @ShawnChin, thank you, it is a bad news but anyway, seems like an answer (please post this as answer, not a comment). As for your question -- the problem is it break the workflow of the program. It is simply more readable when you could put concatenation in another function call, and not make a stop just to create another variable (because of bash limitations).

Comment: I've reworded that as an answer, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do that as a single bash operation. You'll need to perform the concatenation into a variable first follow by the required parameter substitution/expansion.

```
FOO=foooo
TMP=$FOO$FOO  # concatenation
echo "${TMP%o}"  # parameter substitution on concatenated string
```

If you feel that the extra var assignment makes it less readable, you could opt for the less efficient (but more recognisable) approach of piping the output to another command that performs a similar operation, e.g.:

```
[me@home]$ FOO="fooo"

[me@home]$ TMP=$FOO$FOO; echo ${TMP%o}  # bash only, with temp var
fooofoo

[me@home]]$ echo $FOO$FOO | sed 's/o$//'  # pipe to an equivalent operation
fooofoo
```

---

In addition, depending on what your end goal is there may be cleaner ways to accomplish it.

For example, a common situation when concatenation followed by trimming is required would be for path manipulation, i.e.:

```
[me@home]$ APP_ROOT=/opt/myapp
[me@home]$ APP_PATH=/config/hello.cfg
[me@home]$ FULL_PATH=$APP_ROOT$APP_PATH
[me@home]$ echo ${FULL_PATH%/hello.cfg}
/opt/myapp/config
```

In which case the "cleaner" approach would be:

```
[me@home]$ dirname $APP_ROOT$APP_PATH
/opt/myapp/config
```

If you can share what you've trying to achieve perhaps there's a more elegant solution to be had.

Answer (score 0):

See below for two possible answers, depending on exactly what you are looking for:

Answer #1:

```
FOO=fooo
echo "${FOO}${FOO%o}"
```

Output:

```
fooofoo
```

---

Answer #2:

```
FOO=fooo
echo "${FOO%o}${FOO%o}"
```

Output:

```
foofoo
```

---

Answer #3:

```
FOO=fooo
CONCAT="$FOO$FOO"
echo "${CONCAT%ofooo}"

foo
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code above is just an **example**, you have to match entire string (after concatenation) not just the tail. For pattern as long or shorter than tail, it is equivalent, but for substitution longer than tail -- not. Consider `${FOO$FOO%ofooo}`. This should give "foo", and it is possible only when you deal with string as one piece.

Comment: @greenoldman Is there an issue with concatenating them strings first, then doing the substitution? (see updated answer #3)